# In Gilligan's island, what exactly was "the Professor" a Professor of?

Tags: gilligans-island

The pilot episode calls the Professor a "Research Scientist and well known Scout master" [even gives him a *name* as Roy Hinkly!]... but it never really spoke about his *field* of study.

The Professor showed an **unbelievably wide range** of knowledge from various fields, covering everything from basic physics to chemistry to agriculture and languages. This was cleverly done to give plausible reasons for some of the various creations and misadventures that happened on the show.... but *realistically,*  he must have *specialized* in one field. Even as a Scout Master, with a wide breadth of knowledge, he couldn't have covered everything we see him do in the series.

So what exactly were his one, two, or *possibly* three fields of expertise?

I'm open to educated guesses, but canon answers would be preferred.

Comment: "*He has a B.A. from USC, a B.S. from UCLA, an M.A. from SMU, and received his Ph.D from TCU at the age of 15. He has also spent two years on an Egyptian expedition. He also holds a master's degree in psychology and can speak fluent Marubi"*

Comment: @Valorum Thank you, but 2 things:
**1.** What's the source for this quote? and...
**2.** This still offers almost _no_ solid information! We know his _number_ of degrees, but **not ONE of their fields,** so it could be anything from Physics to aeronautics to chemistry to botany, or literally _anything_ else!

The Egyptian expedition would infer he has a learned understanding, at least, of archaeology and history, but _both_ of those are context specific. The degree in psychology and mastery of Marubi are the only two specific areas we know he is a **stated expert** in.

Comment: 1. Straight off Wikipedia. I assume googling for the quotes would give you the episodes 2. Hence why I didn't post it as an answer

Comment: I recall one time he told us his specialty was "the mating cycle of the angleworm".

Comment: @Spencer so he's an _entomologist_ then? Well, that would explain his background in Biology, if only to a _limited_ degree.... but it gives no context for his scope of knowledge in chemistry, physics, or engineering, **All** of which he's shown some capacity for throughout the show. Were there any others like that saying what he was researching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's botany. Multiple websites (listed below) mention his principle area of expertise as botany. There is actually a fan page, gilligansisle.com, and it says that the whole reason he was even on the SS Minnow was for research for a book he was writing entitled "Fun with Ferns". So while he does hold multiple degrees, it seems he is most likely a professor of botany.

http://www.gilligansisle.com/prof.html
 mentions his various degrees and then explains that he was on the boat for research on his book "Fun with Ferns"

https://www.charactour.com/hub/characters/view/Roy-Hinkley.Gilligans-Island
On this page, the first paragraph mentions his expertise in botany and the second paragraph makes mention of him researching his book.

https://wikivisually.com/wiki/The_Professor_(Gilligan's_Island)
In the character summary on this page it mentions his expertise in botany as well as researching for his book.